# Is there any similar function to glibc mtrace() function in c++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, mtrace

I am a c programmer and I am new in c++. In c we have mtrace() function to trace information about allocation and deallocation memory. 
Is there any similar function which could do that but in c++.

Answer (score 4):

`mtrace` is not "in C"; it's a utility provided by GLIBC, that has a C binding.

If you're still using GLIBC with your C++ applications, which you probably are, you can still use `mtrace` (unless you have some custom allocator that doesn't use `malloc`/`free`, but then that would be a problem for *any* leak detector).

However, [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) would be more appropriate for this task. It is more feature-rich and evolved. For example, [`mtrace` only works on single-threaded programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mtrace). `mtrace` is also limited in the information it can give you, whereas Valgrind (in combination with some other tools) [can be a real force of nature](https://www.google.com/search?q=massif+visualiser&tbm=isch).

Comment: I agree with is mt-unsave and in the question I said glibc function.

Comment: @Masalkhi "In c we have mtrace() function" ;)

Comment: Hahah, So there is no such similar function in c++ standard library for new and delete ? I need a function rather then a tool

Comment: @Masalkhi `new` and `delete` use `malloc` and `free` by default mate. new and delete are not allocation functions. They're not "the C++ version" of malloc/free

Comment: Oh Alright, awesome, if they use malloc and free by default so I could use mallopt() and mcheck() functions in c++ code, right ?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Answer (score 1):

mtrace() works in C++ as well, but with C++ it almost always return the addresses where **new** and **delete** are called in the code, with no more information from stack for example, which gives limited ability to identify the problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

C++ memory management is just a bunch of language features on top of C.
I'm not a fan of valgrind, it's just too slow.
I would recommend [ASAN](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer). It's built into GCC/Clang and has many options to play with.